# How to effectively constrain a view in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view, zbar-sdk

I currently have a project in which there is a view controller that contains several subviews, one of which displays a camera feed that uses an SDK to read barcodes. The SDK is called ZBar if anyone is familiar with their library. I am using a storyboard to place these views and using auto layout to try and constrain the view to the size that I want it on the screen. However when I try and run the app, the camera view inflates to what seems like a pretty random size. My question is how can I prevent this inflation from happening and why does it override the auto layout constraints that I set on the storyboard?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scannerView, resultText;

-(void) viewDidLoad{
barcodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"15044213", nil];
names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Summer", nil];
scannerView.readerDelegate = self;

[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
[scannerView start];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated
{
[scannerView stop];
}

- (void) readerView: (ZBarReaderView*) view
 didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet*) syms
      fromImage: (UIImage*) img
{
for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) {
    resultText.text = sym.data;
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: man your code formatting is so hard to read

Comment: Yeah sorry it copied really weirdly, really weird indentations

Comment: Could you maybe add screeenshots of your storyboard and simulator screen?